# bootstrap-fullscreen-select fire onchange event?

Tags: jquery

I am using select option for full screen http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/
It can't fire onchange event, any idea?

```
<select name="select_year" id="select_year" class="form-control mobileSelect">
   <option value='abc'> abc </option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#select_year').on('change', function() {
         alert( "asdaS" );
    })
});
```

Thanks for @Justinas. I have success fire onchange event. Here is what i did :

Add the following codes :

```
onClose: function(){
    alert('onClose: '+$(this).val());
},
onOpen: function(){
    alert('onOpen: '+this.val());
}
```

inside :

```
$('.mobileSelect').mobileSelect({
    animation: 'scale',
    animationSpeed: 400,
});
```

become :

```
$('.mobileSelect').mobileSelect({
    animation: 'scale',
    animationSpeed: 400,
    onClose: function(){
        alert('onClose: '+$(this).val());
    },
    onOpen: function(){
        alert('onOpen: '+this.val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Because it fires it's own events: http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select#callbacks

Comment: Thank you. It works.